# Join evaluation order in HIVE

Tags: sql, join, hive

I was trying to run a query that would make use of multiple joins inside HIVE.

example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2          -- the table resulted from the inner join should be left joined to table1
INNER JOIN table3         -- this inner join should happen first between table2 and table3
ON table3.id = table2.id
ON table2.id = table1.id
```

I think this is perfectly valid on other SQL DBMS's, but HIVE gives me an error. Are this kind of joins ( I really don't know what to call them so I can't google them) illegal in HIVE?

Workarounds would be some subquery unions, but I am more interested in getting more information on this kind of syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not valid in any database, each `JOIN` sentence must have it's respective `ON` clause. You need to set the last `ON` (`ON table2.id = table1.id`) after the `LEFT JOIN` with `table2`

Comment: it is valid, here are some articles on it: https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/take-control-joins
https://dg-sql.blogspot.com/2017/03/what-kind-of-join-syntax-is-this.html

Comment: Thanks @habarnam, it would be good you to study that link, maybe after you won't need to create these questions

Comment: don't be rude, jaime, the question was refering to HIVE in particular. you should study that link before you comment that it's not valid in any database

Comment: I am not being rude... I just gave you an aswer to your question, and you just look at my comment, to give a link with, maybe, the answer for your question. Why do you ask if you respond your own questions?...

Comment: this is not the answer to my question. my question was if this syntax was in any way allowed in HIVE, as I couldn't find any docs on it. and I couldn't make it work the general syntax, as I said in the post, is valid in theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid SQL syntax and should be parsed as:

```
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     (table2 INNER JOIN
      table3 
      ON table3.id = table2.id
     )
     ON table2.id = table1.id
```

By convention, `ON` clauses are interleaved with `JOIN`s, sot the conditions are where the `JOIN` is specified.  However, the syntax allows for this construct as well.

I don't use such syntax -- and I strongly discourage using it without parentheses -- but I thought pretty much all databases supported it.

If parentheses don't work, you have two options.  One is a subquery:

This is valid SQL syntax and should be parsed as:

```
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT table2.id, . . . -- other columns you want
      FROM table2 INNER JOIN
           table3 
           ON table3.id = table2.id
     ) t23
     ON t23.id = table1.id
```

Or using a `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT table2 INNER JOIN
       table3
       ON table3.id = table2.id RIGHT JOIN
       table1
       ON table2.id = table1.id
```

In this case, the `RIGHT JOIN` should be equivalent.  But it can be complicated getting exactly the same semantics when multiple joins are involved (and without using parentheses).

Comment: unfortunately i cannot get this to work - with paranthesis it gives me a "cannot recognize input" error on the paranthesis line, without paranthesis it gives me a "cannot recognize input" error on the second "ON"  - maybe hive just doesn't allow such syntax